# C# + Reading output result from stored procedure + merge into + OUTPUT

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to upload an Excel file in C# to SQL Server database table.

The table looks like this:

**Companies**

```
ID(PK)          Int            AutoIncrement 
CompanyName     Varchar(256)
Logo            Varchar(256)
WebsiteURL      Varchar(256)
Description     Varchar(256)
```

I have read the Excel into a `DataTable` object and passed it to a stored procedure. The stored procedure uses `MERGE INTO` to insert new records and update existing.

I need to know how many records are inserted and how many are updated.

For this, I used `OUTPUT` like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_Companies]
     @tblCompanies CompanyType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @summary CompanySummaryType;

    MERGE INTO companies c1
    USING @tblCompanies c2 ON c1.CompanyName = c2.CompanyName

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
       UPDATE 
           SET c1.Logo = c2.Logo,
               c1.WebsiteURL = c2.WebsiteURL,
               c1.CompanyDescription = c2.CompanyDescription,

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (CompanyName, Logo, WebsiteURL, Description) 
        VALUES (c2.CompanyName, c2.Logo, c2.WebsiteURL, c2.Description)

    OUTPUT 
        $action as ActionType, 
        INSERTED.CompanyName as CompanyName INTO @summary;
END
```

`CompanyType` is a user-defined table type containing table columns

CompanySummaryType is a user-defined table type containing two columns:

```
ActionType    Varchar(256),
CompanyName   Varchar(256)
```

The code runs fine and insert or update working perfectly.

I want to read the `@summary` variable back in my C# code.

Right now, I am using `ExecuteNonQuery` to execute stored procedure like this:

```
private void AddRecords(DataTable dataTable)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update_Companies"))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblCompanies", dataTable);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, is there a way by which I can find how many records failed to insert or update?

Comment: Why would any records fail to insert or update?   Provide sample data and desired result.

Comment: Records don't fail, unless they don't do anything because of a flaw in your logic. They will either UPDATE or INSERT as per the MERGE statement. Besides, you're asking about OUTPUT. Totally different thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `@Summary` variable an OUTPUT parameter of the procedure.

In your C# code, you can then compare the returned OUTPUT parameter, with the original input parameter, to see which rows were not inserted or updated.